# Transpose and BinCounts leading to "cannot be transposed" error message

Tags: list-manipulation

I am currently working on a code written by someone else and I am having a hard time with a `Transpose` command using `BinCounts`. When I try to run it, the program doesn't plot anything showing the message:
`Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {{89625.6,89625.6,89625.6,89625.7,89625.7,89625.7,89625.7,89625.7,89625.7,89625.7,89625.7,89625.7,89625.7,89625.7,89625.7,89625.7,89625.7,<<17>>,89625.8,89625.8,89625.8,89625.8,89625.8,89625.9,89625.9,89625.9,89625.9,89625.9,89625.9,89625.9,89625.9,89625.9,89625.9,89625.9,<<150>>},{0,619,<<48>>,<<149>>}} cannot be transposed.`

As I am not familiar with these commands and the code was written a long time ago, I'm not sure how to correct this, if it's a syntax issue or something else. I will insert the code below:

```
  Subscript[B, 0] = 89626;
  Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 0]=2.0679*10^-7*10^16;
  a = Sqrt[(2Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 0])/(Sqrt[3]*Subscript[B, 0])];   
  K[m_,n_] =Sqrt[(2*Pi^2*Subscript[B, 0])/(Sqrt[3] Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 0])]*{-Sqrt[3]n,2m-n};
  \[Xi]0=Sqrt[Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 0]/(2*Pi*Hc2)] /. {Hc2-> 120000};
  pars = {\[Xi]->\[Xi]0,\[Lambda]->5000,Nn->2,Nm->2};
  K[n,m].K[n,m]*\[Xi]^2 /. pars // Expand
  B[x_,y_][pars_]:=With[{Nm=Lookup[pars,Nm],Nn=Lookup[pars,Nn], \[Xi]=Lookup[pars,\[Xi]],\[Lambda]=Lookup[pars,\[Lambda]]},Subscript[B, 0] +Subscript[B, 0] \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(m = \(-Nm\)\), \(Nm\)]\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = \(-Nn\)\), \(Nm\)]If[m == 0\  && \ n == 0, 0, If[K[n, m] . K[n, m]*\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Xi]\), \(2\)]\ \  < 0.05, 0, \*FractionBox[\(Exp[\(-\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Xi]\), \(2\)]\)*K[m, n] . K[m, n]/2]\), \(1 + \*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(2\)]*K[m, n] . K[m, n]\)]] Cos[K[m, n] . {x, y}]]\)\) ]

  listOrbital=Table[B[x,y][pars]-Subscript[B, 0] /. {x->RandomReal[{0,a}],y->RandomReal[{0,Sqrt[3]/2*a}]},{i,1,1000000}];
  Bmin=Min[listOrbital]
  Bmax =Max[listOrbital]
  Bdist = Table[1.03*Bmin+i*(Bmax-Bmin)*1.03/200+Subscript[B, 0],{i,1,200}];
  ListPlot[Transpose[{Bdist,BinCounts[listOrbital,{1.03*Bmin,1.03*Bmax,(Bmax-Bmin)*1.035/200}]}],PlotJoined->True,PlotRange->All]
```

(sorry about the confusing format!)

Comment: The problem seems to be that `Bdist` and the output of `BinCounts` are list of different length. Sorry that I cannot help you any further, but I can simply not decipher the meaning of the code.

Comment: Yes, try `Length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the second close look, I wondered where the `1.035` in the bin width specification comes from

```
BinCounts[listOrbital, {1.03*Bmin, 1.03*Bmax, (Bmax - Bmin)*1.035/200}]
```

From the context, I guess that 200 bins are desired. But the bin width is slightly to large, so that only 199 bins are created. I think this is just a typo and it should read

```
BinCounts[listOrbital, {1.03*Bmin, 1.03*Bmax, (Bmax - Bmin)*1.03/200}]
```

The plot works fine after this replacement.

**Side remark**

The way to compute `listOrbital` is awfully inefficient. You might be much better off by exploiting that basic arithmetic operations are `Listable` with

```
num = 1000000;
x = RandomReal[{0, a}, num];
y = RandomReal[{0, Sqrt[3]/2*a}, num];
listOrbital = B[x, y][pars] - Subscript[B, 0] ;
```

This way, the `Lookups` and the logic in the sums is evaluated only once, and the summation is performed on packed vectors instead of scalars.

On my machine, this takes about 2.3 seconds, while OP's code might take more than 600 seconds. (I ran it for `num = 10000;` which took 6 seconds and I extrapolated from there.)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! It was taking a long time to compute this! :)

Comment: That's why I posted this. You're welcome!

Comment: You are right! I didn't notice it was 1.035 there. I suppose OP was testing this number of bins. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, to troubleshoot code do not use `1000000` iterations. `100` is a better starting value.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Subscript[B, 0] = 89626;
Subscript[Φ, 0] = 2.0679*10^-7*10^16 // Rationalize;

a = Sqrt[(2 Subscript[Φ, 0])/(Sqrt[3]*Subscript[B, 0])];

K[m_, n_] = Sqrt[(2*Pi^2*Subscript[B, 0])/
     (Sqrt[3] Subscript[Φ, 0])]*{-Sqrt[3] n, 2 m - n};

ξ0 = Sqrt[Subscript[Φ, 0]/(2*Pi*Hc2)] /. {Hc2 -> 120000} // N[#, 15] &;

pars = {ξ -> ξ0, λ -> 5000, Nn -> 2, Nm -> 2};

B[x_, y_][pars_] := With[{
   Nm = Lookup[pars, Nm], Nn = Lookup[pars, Nn], 
   ξ = Lookup[pars, ξ], λ = Lookup[pars, λ]}, 
  Subscript[B, 0] + Subscript[B, 0]*
    Sum[
     If[m == 0 && n == 0, 0, 
             If[K[n, m] . K[n, m]*ξ^2 < 0.05, 0, 
                 Exp[(-ξ^2)*(K[m, n].K[m, n]/2)]/
                   (1 + λ^2*K[m, n].K[m, n])]*Cos[K[m, n].{x, y}]], 
           {m, -Nm, Nm}, {n, -Nn, Nm}]]
```

Using Henrik's more efficient code

```
SeedRandom[1234]

num = 1000000;
x = RandomReal[{0, a}, num];
y = RandomReal[{0, Sqrt[3]/2*a}, num];
listOrbital = B[x, y][pars] - Subscript[B, 0];

Bmin = Min[listOrbital];
Bmax = Max[listOrbital];

Bdist = Table[1.03*Bmin + i*(Bmax - Bmin)*1.03/200 + Subscript[B, 0], {i, 1, 200}];
```

Since [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) indicates that there is a problem, check the [`Length`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html) of the lists being transposed.

```
Length /@ {Bdist, 
  BinCounts[listOrbital, {1.03*Bmin, 1.03*Bmax, (Bmax - Bmin)*1.035/200}]}

(* {200, 199} *)
```

Change the `200` divisor to `201`, then

```
ListPlot[
 Transpose[
  {Bdist, BinCounts[
    listOrbital, {1.03*Bmin, 1.03*Bmax, (Bmax - Bmin)*1.035/201}]}],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful! :)